# Material overridden when importing package between 2 pc

Tags: unity, materials, import, export

So I work with my colleague A
and he has (for example) a basic scene
[image]

A exports the scene as package to give me.
[image]

and on my pc with new project I imported the package
[image]

everything is fine
[image]

and I make adjustment on material, and rename the scene and material
[image]

then I export the scene as package as well
[image]

now back to A's computer, he imports my package into his project with that basic scene
[image]

Wow ! In my scene, the new material is not assigned rather is the old red one.
[image]

How is this happening ? Please save me thank you

Comment: In the recipient's project, can you open the Assets folder in the file browser, and find the ".Meta" files associated with each of these materials? Open them up in a text editor and find their GUIDs. Compare these to the GUID for the material in the source project.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I checked it, and they are different though, bu how can I solve this ? (maybe not export as package ?)

Comment: My best guess is that Unity changes the GUID of the imported item when it detects a collision with an existing asset. You might want to try duplicating the material and renaming the duplicate, instead of renaming the original. That way it should get a new, non-colliding GUID.

Comment: Hmmm, good guess, I should give it a try, thanks a lot, I'll reply you should anything happen

Comment: If good things happen, feel free to post it as an Answer that can help future readers too. 

Comment: Yes, it worked ! although the id is still different but somehow it succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that Unity changes the GUID of the imported item when it detects a collision with an existing asset. You might want to try duplicating the material and renaming the duplicate, instead of renaming the original. That way it should get a new, non-colliding GUID. (from DMGregory

Comment: This answer would be better if you wrote it in your own words, describing (or illustrating) the steps you took to solve the problem.